# AngularJS Server Side Pagination - Recursively call API

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination

I'm trying to call an API that takes parameters start and count, like this:

```
function handleSuccess() {
    if (!!response.data) {
            return (response.data);
        } else {
            return q.reject(response.data);
        }
}
function handleError() {
    // do some handling
}

function getData(url, sortBy) {

    var count = 10;
    var start = 1;

    var request = http({
            cache: true,
            method: "GET",
            url: url,
            params: {
                sortBy: sortBy,
                sortOrder: "ASC",
                count: count, // e.g. 10
                start: start  // e.g. 1

            }
        });
        return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
}
```

The JSON response from the API could contain a "next" link that would give me the URL to call to get the next set of data if there exists more...this is how the pagination works.

What's the best way to do this and concatenate all the data returned into one JSON response?

Comment: Don't cache your `get` request and in `handleSuccess` and/or `handleError` call `getData` again with the correct parameters.

Comment: how to concatenate the results though? @J.Wells

Comment: i added code that i currently have in handleSuccess()

Comment: You would just concat to your model. Your model should already contain the last retrieved results. When the new results come in, `myThing.myCollection = myThing.myCollection.concat(newResults);`

Comment: Also, your `if (!!response.data)` can just be `if (response.data)`. There's no reason to convert `response.data`'s truthiness to a boolean for that evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some part of the `data` response is an array, then simply use normal array `concat()` to combine it with previous pages of data in your `handleSuccess()` callback.

Comment: How do I get "previous pages of data" while in my handleSuccess() callback?  I seem to only have access to the current data and can't save the data in a global variable.

Comment: It is a matter of understanding scope, you need to access a variable outside your scope. Read up on it is the best way to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that a service-oriented way is most useful when trying to get paged data from the same endpoint as it is easy to share services and objects between controllers and directives.

First, I would set up the service layer of your application so that all objects being requested have common, generic methods like so (I highly recommend you use ngResource or RESTAngular or something like that):

```
    angular.module('myModule')
        .factory('ApiObject', function($http, $q) {
            ApiObject = function ApiObject(attributes) {
                angular.extend(this, attributes);
            };

            ApiObject.query = function(url, parameters) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.get(url, {params: parameters}).then(function(data) {
                    var results = [];
                    angular.forEach(data, function(apiObject) {
                        results.push(new ApiObject(apiObject));
                    });
                    deferred.resolve(results);
                }, function(error) {
                    // Do error stuff
                    deferred.reject(error);
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            };

            return ApiObject;
        });
```

Then set up a service to manage your paging data that accepts your generic services as well as parameters and configuration options. Also allow for events to be triggered within the service (see `trigger` and `on` methods) so that you know when new results are fetched. I've also written in a way for the results to be automatically concatenated onto the current result set:

```
    angular.module('myModule')
        .factory('SearchService', function() {
            SearchService = function SearchService(service, params, config) {
                this.searchParams = params || {};
                this.config = config || {};
                this.service = service;
                this.results = [];
                this.listeners = {};
            };

            SearchService.prototype.fetch = function(params) {
                var _this = this;
                this.service.query().then(function(results) {
                    if(_this.config.concatResults) {
                        _this.results = _this.results.concat(results);
                       // You probably should make sure results are unique at this point as that is a common problem with paging a changing API
                    } else {
                        _this.results = results;
                    }

                    _this.trigger('searchSuccess', _this.results);
                });
            };

            SearchService.prototype.on = function(event, listener) {
                (this.listeners[event] = (this.listeners[event] || [])).push(listener);
            };

            SearchService.prototype.trigger = function(event, payload) {
                angular.forEach(this.listeners[event], function(listener) {
                    listener(payload);
                });
            };

            SearchService.prototype.isLastPage = function() {
                //logic here to determine last page
            };

            SearchService.prototype.nextPage = function() {
                if(this.isLastPage()) {
                    return;
                }
                if(this.searchParams.page) {
                    this.searchParams.page++;
                } else {
                    this.searchParams.page = 2;
                }

                this.fetch();
            };

            // Write more methods for previousPage, lastPage, firstPage, goToPage... etc.

            return SearchService;
        });
```

Then in your controller, you're going to want to instantiate the search service with some default parameters and configuration and then fetch the first page:

```
   angular.module('myModule')
        .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, ApiObject, SearchService) {
            $scope.searchService = new SearchService(ApiObject, {page: 1}, {concatResults: true});

            $scope.searchService.on('searchSuccess', function(results) {
                // Do something with results if you wish, but they'll already be stored in $scope.searchService
            });

            // Get the first page of data
            $scope.searchService.fetch();
        });
```

This is obviously a rough cut with a lot of room for improvement, but I hope this will be a good jumping off point to get you pointed in some sort of angular-style direction. In my experience, this is the best way to abstract out paging logic from the data/request layer in your services.